# Using C#, is it possible to create a class that utilizes an object within its definition?

Tags: c#, oop, class-design

I am creating a Blazor WebAssembly app, and I have two classes (shown below). In WorkDay I want to calculate how much I will pay in taxes by using PayRate from the Job class. How can I get this to work?

```
public class WorkDay
{
    

    public double Hours { get; set; } 
    public double? Subtotal { get; set; }
    public double TaxRate { get; set; } = 0.1;
    public double Taxes
    {
        get { return ((Hours * 15.74) * TaxRate); } 
    }
    public double? Final 
    {
        get { return ((Hours * 15.74) - Taxes); }
    }

}
```

And

```
public class Job
{
    public Job(string organization, double payRate)
    {
        Organization = organization;
        PayRate = payRate;
    }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    public double? PayRate { get; set; }
    public List<int> PayDays { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    public List<PayPeriod> PayPeriods { get; set; } = new List<PayPeriod>();
}
```

Comment: `Job` is a class. There could be many instances (objects) of it. Which of those hypothetical instances should a `WorkDay` object use to get the `PayRate`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```cs
class B {
    public int hourlyRate { get; set; }
}

class A {
    public B b { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, but I got the error "CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PayRate' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)".

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is `WorkDay` has a dependency on Job, so you need to add it as a property or field and set it in the constructor.

[Before someone jumps on me about SRP and other principles] There are other probably better ways of doing this, but without more context, it's impossible to comment constructively.

```cs
public class WorkDay
{
    public Job Job {get; private set;}
    public double Hours { get; set; } 
    public double? Subtotal { get; set; }
    public double TaxRate { get; set; } = 0.1;

    public double Taxes => ((Hours * this.Job.PayRate) * TaxRate); 
    public double? Final => (Hours * this.Job.PayRate) - Taxes);

    public WorkDay(Job job)
    {
       this.Job = job;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Job
{
    public Job(string organization, double payRate)
    {
        this.Organization = organization;
        this.PayRate = payRate;
    }
    public string Organization { get; set; }
    // Set in Ctor so should not be nullable
    public double PayRate { get; set; }
    public List<int> PayDays { get; set; } = new List<int>();
    public List<PayPeriod> PayPeriods { get; set; } = new List<PayPeriod>();
}
```

Comment: all these setters seem overkill. It's exposing all internals. But that's a bit out of scope for this Q-A.

Comment: @JHBonarius - Which is exactly why I qualified my answer with "[Before someone jumps on me about SRP and other principles]". ;-)   I was trying to make minimal changes to the existing code.  Talking SRP and mutation control is way outside the scope of an SO answer.  My `Workday` would be an immutable record.